# Restrict Mobile data but exclude some apps

Tags: data-monitoring

My daughter has a mobile plan that has a restriction on the data she can use each month. But it comes with unlimited Facebook, 4square, Instagram and Twitter.

I want to setup her phone so that she can use as much of the above 4 apps as she wants but the rest of the data gets restricted above the cap.

It is a Galaxy S2 running CM10

Can this be done?

Comment: I don't know of any solution off the shelf; and I cannot think of anything custom that *just works*. Problem: accurate mobile data measurement is impossible with current carrier accounting practices. They measure sent data, but with UDP there's no guarantee sent data will actually reach your phone. E.g. a big UDP video stream is accounted completely but your connection only transmitted half of it. If you however receive a "data plan exhausted" SMS, you could use "tasker" to activate "droidwall" with a setting that just does allow those 4 services.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know if there is a txt when the allocation is exhausted. I wonder if, and I realise it won't be accurate, tasker could monitor the in built data monitor so when it alerts droidwall could kick in? I haven't used Tasker, but I will look into it. Thanks

Comment: Tasker might be able to monitor data usage, of course. I just noticed that it's unreliable, because Android measures what arrives on the phone and a carrier accounts all data sent over air. Always wondered why I got that 80% SMS message when I only calculated 76% or so. YMMV, just don't rely on it if you get charged per MB after you reach the plan's limit. Izzy has a list of links, it's mostly German but there are some en. links too: http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/forum/thread/435917/Tasker-Ressourcen-Sammlung

Answer (score 1):

You are running CM10 in your phone. So its rooted. You can restrict Mobile data usage with some exceptions for specific apps by an app called [Droidwall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.droidwall.free&hl=en) fro playstore.
This app is seful to specify which apps can use Mobile data and which cannot.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips. Looks promising. I will report back.