# How to turn off data usage for all but specific App in android?

Tags: wi-fi, sync, mobile-data

I want to disable the auto sync(i.e mobile data) for all of my App ,except whatsApp when I am in mobile data connection.So basically talking , when I am on mobile data I only want to use whatsApp to connect to internet.

But when I am connected to wifi , any of App can update,sync and do things whatever they want. How can I do that ?

EDIT: MY PHONE IS NOT ROOTED

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enable Mobile Data only for select apps on a rooted phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7976/how-do-i-enable-mobile-data-only-for-select-apps-on-a-rooted-phone)

Comment: my phone is not rooted so that answer is irrelevent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of applications (3G Watchdog for example) which allow you to restrict background data to WiFi; therefore when you've left the application it cannot continually use data.

In later versions of Android you can go to Settings > Data Usage > Apps and restrict background data, thus not needing a third party app. Both methods do not require root access. 
Here are a few related questions:[MMS and Restricting background data](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47250/mms-and-restricting-background-data), [Restrict Mobile data but exclude some apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34593/restrict-mobile-data-but-exclude-some-apps) or [How does "Restrict background data" work?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/55831/how-does-restrict-background-data-work).

The above mentioned will give much more explanation on what to do, why to do etc. but I will just give you the means to read it. It's quite an easy process to compelte. I will, however, give an alternative which is not often used: [AutoMateIt](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=AutomateIt.mainPackage). Let me know if you manage to incorportate this into your issue!

Comment: I just restricted background data .